# Terminate QThread when GUI exits

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I am using QThreads to run a function in the background, but when I exit the GUI application, the QThread still continues to run.

There are examples about C++ but I do not know how to implement them in python

```
class PF35Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    signalPF35 = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
    def run(self):
        newcase = newcaseList[-1]
        os.system('EAZ{0}(3,5).EAZ{0}(3,5).OUT'.format(newcase))
        self.signalPF35.emit()
```

How do I terminate QThread when GUI closes?

Comment: What does `os.system('EAZ{0}(3,5).EAZ{0}(3,5).OUT'.format(newcase))`? , if you want to finish the thread you should finish that task.

Comment: @eyllanesc Its a third party program. I want to be able to finish the thread when application is open, but if user exits the entire application, it should stop the thread. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The idea, as I have already indicated, is to finish this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case the thread is only necessary because os.system() is blocking, but if you use QProcess it does a similar task and you do not need the thread, it also allows easier management with the Qt eventloop.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    signalPF35 = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start task", clicked=self.on_clicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        newcase = newcaseList[-1]
        self._process.start('EAZ{0}(3,5).EAZ{0}(3,5).OUT'.format(newcase))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.signalPF35.emit()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._process.kill()
        super(MainWindow, self).closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Won't the process freeze the GUI if its on the main thread? I am using QThreads to keep the GUI available for user.

Comment: Could you explain why you used pyqtslot decorators, as the methods would work without them? Also why keep the self.signalPF35.emit() if the method runs when process is finished?

Comment: @Drees 1) The use of @pyqtSlot() is not mandatory but if it is beneficial, read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator 2) I still emit signalPF35 because I did not want to modify your logic, I do not know why you use signalPF35.

Comment: Since I am trying to access a third party program, using a cmd prompt, how do you start it with QProcess, as self._process.start("EAZ {0}(1,1).EAZ {0}(1,1).OUT".format(newcase)) does not work